# Merging by minute YFin and Tweepy sentiment score gives empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sentiment-analysis, yfinance

Hello I would like to merge the two dataframes (minute-level price from YFinance,DF1, and sentiment score from Tweepy,DF2) but the following codes give me an empty dataframe:

Structure of DF1:

```
Datetime                                                                    
2021-03-30 12:00:00-04:00  331.290009  331.480011  331.290009  331.480011   
2021-03-30 12:01:00-04:00  331.679993  331.709991  331.549988  331.609985   
2021-03-30 12:02:00-04:00  331.640015  331.640015  331.209991  331.209991   
2021-03-30 12:03:00-04:00  331.290009  331.459991  331.190002  331.428009   
2021-03-30 12:04:00-04:00  331.480011  331.480011  331.339996  331.359985   
...                               ...         ...         ...         ...   
2021-03-31 11:55:00-04:00  327.269989  327.359985  327.239990  327.359985   
2021-03-31 11:56:00-04:00  327.299988  327.380005  327.184998  327.279999   
2021-03-31 11:57:00-04:00  327.190002  327.234985  327.109985  327.234985   
2021-03-31 11:58:00-04:00  327.230011  327.369995  327.200012  327.279999   
2021-03-31 11:59:00-04:00  327.325012  327.630005  327.245087  327.245087   

                            Adj Close  Volume  
Datetime                                       
2021-03-30 12:00:00-04:00  331.480011       0  
2021-03-30 12:01:00-04:00  331.609985    2260  
2021-03-30 12:02:00-04:00  331.209991    1886  
2021-03-30 12:03:00-04:00  331.428009    3569  
2021-03-30 12:04:00-04:00  331.359985    2191  
...                               ...     ...  
2021-03-31 11:55:00-04:00  327.359985    4419  
2021-03-31 11:56:00-04:00  327.279999    4428  
2021-03-31 11:57:00-04:00  327.234985    2098  
2021-03-31 11:58:00-04:00  327.279999    3447  
2021-03-31 11:59:00-04:00  327.245087    7598
```

Structure of DF2

```
                        Time        Date  Compound  Subjectivity  Polarity  \
0  2021-03-31 23:58:23-05:00  2021-03-31    0.6369      0.300000  1.000000   
1  2021-03-31 23:57:25-05:00  2021-03-31    0.6369      0.300000  1.000000   
2  2021-03-31 23:56:57-05:00  2021-03-31    0.5719      0.427273  0.068182   
3  2021-03-31 23:56:52-05:00  2021-03-31    0.6369      0.300000  1.000000   
4  2021-03-31 23:56:31-05:00  2021-03-31    0.5994      0.287500 -0.031250   
5  2021-03-31 23:56:16-05:00  2021-03-31    0.5719      0.427273  0.068182   
6  2021-03-31 23:55:45-05:00  2021-03-31    0.0000      0.700000  0.000000   
7  2021-03-31 23:53:08-05:00  2021-03-31    0.5719      0.427273  0.068182   
8  2021-03-31 23:45:36-05:00  2021-03-31    0.6369      0.300000  1.000000   
9  2021-03-31 23:43:21-05:00  2021-03-31    0.6369      0.300000  1.000000   
10 2021-03-31 23:39:37-05:00  2021-03-31    0.0000      0.700000  0.000000   
11 2021-03-31 23:39:20-05:00  2021-03-31    0.3818      0.560000  0.140000   
12 2021-03-31 23:38:38-05:00  2021-03-31    0.6369      0.300000  1.000000
```

I want to merge them into one DF according to their time and I ran this:

```
output = tweet_df.merge(price, left_index= True, right_index= True)
print(output)
print('Finish combining price and sentiment')
```

An empty DF is returned

```
Finish creating price
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Tweet_content, Time, Date, Compound, Subjectivity, Polarity, Compound_analysis, Polarity_analysis, Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume]
Index: []
Finish combining price and sentiment
```

Recalling I have to index the two DFs to align them and I ran this:

```
tweet_df.index = pd.to_datetime(tweet_df.index)
price.index = pd.to_datetime(price.index)
output = tweet_df.merge(price, left_index= True, right_index= True)
print(output)
```

This gives me an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot join tz-naive with tz-aware DatetimeIndex
```

Anyone know how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance :D

Comment: I think you should specify right-on , left-on parameters. Check the docs about merge here. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: See my hint for your problem below that probably could locate your source of error.  Anyway, even if the error is rectified, you may still need to fine-tune your program since it looks like from the sample data that you have no common data for the 2 dataframes to merge in the way a you expect.

Comment: What I mean by no common data is because the first dataframe has time down to minutes and the second one down to seconds. So, probably the merge result will be empty too with the default inner join.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have to make sure both of the 2 dataframes have date/time values as index.  If one of them is not in datetime format, you will get the error.

As seen from the data samples of the 2 datafames, look like DF1 has **row index** named `'Datetime'` which is correctly in datetime format while DF2 has the **row index** just normal range index, that is (0, 1, 2, ...)  The column `'Time'` in DF2 is just a data column instead of index.   You need to make the column `'Time'` as row index as follows before performing other tasks:

```
tweet_df = tweet_df.set_index('Time')
```

If that still doesn't work, probably one of your dataframe is tz-naive and the other one is tz-aware.  You can try to convert either one of them to tz-aware by [`pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html) in your codes converting index to datetime format.  For example:

```
tweet_df.index = pd.to_datetime(tweet_df.index).tz_localize('UTC')    # or any other tz suitable for you
```

Or,

```
price.index = pd.to_datetime(price.index).tz_localize('UTC')    # or any other tz suitable for you
```